# "The Two Sheriffs" puzzle

Tags: co.combinatorics, coding-theory, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

This puzzle is taken from the book *Mathematical puzzles: a connoisseur's collection* by *P. Winkler*.

> Two sheriffs in neighboring towns are on the track of a killer, in a
>   case involving eight suspects. By virtue of independent, reliable 
>   detective work, each has narrowed his list to only two. Now they are
>   engaged in a telephone call; their object is to compare information,
>   and if their pairs overlap in just one suspect, to identify the killer.
>
> The difficulty is that their telephone line has been tapped by
>   the local lynch mob, who know the original list of suspects but not
>   which pairs the sheriffs have arrived at. If they are able to identify
>   the killer with certainty as a result of the phone call, he will be
>   lynched before he can be arrested.
>
> Can the sheriffs, who have never met, conduct their conversation
>   in such a way that they both end up knowing who the killer is (when
>   possible), yet the lynch mob is still left in the dark?

It has different solutions. But the question is **why this puzzle is unsolvable for seven suspects?**

Original problem was discussed at [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/). There are some solutions [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11267/two-sheriffs-and-eavesdroppers).

**EDT.** Let me summarize the discussion from comments.

1. Formal success conditions (due to usul): "A deterministic communication protocol such that, for any singly-overlapping sets held by the sheriffs, the sheriffs always deduce the correct suspect, and the mob has no deterministic strategy to always guess the correct suspect."
2. It is a mathematical problem. Original problem has absolutely consistent solution. (It does not use any cryptographic assumptions.)
3. Puzzling [solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11267/two-sheriffs-and-eavesdroppers/11278#11278) is wrong and the number of suspects is important here.
4. (Due to usul.) This problem is very close to many types of problems in CS, such as zero-knowledge proofs and secure multiparty communication, but so far it is not clear if exactly this type of problem being studied.

Comment: Does the solution for eight suspects depend on $8$ being a power of $2$?

Comment: Yes. Any solution is some kind of division by $2$.

Comment: Your question is perhaps more suitable for the [puzzling](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com) stack exchange website?

Comment: Is 7 equivalent to 8, except that the "lynch mob" has also managed to eliminate one of the suspects? Which makes the task easier for them?

Comment: @Yakky Not quite.  The suspect eliminated by the lynch mob would have to also be eliminated by each of the sheriffs.

Comment: @coudy 8 suspects and overlaping pairs is a puzzle, more general situation is not.

Comment: What are the rules governing their conversation? If they can simply use public-key cryptography, then the problem is not particularly interesting!

Comment: @James Cranch It is a mathematical problem. Original problem has absolutely consistent solution. (It does not use any cryptographic assumptions.)

Comment: I think there is a valid mathematical question here that is better asked either here or MSE, depending on what level it is, rather than on a puzzle site. However, to fit MO, you should at least link to what is known. You can use a spoiler mark-up: Start each paragraph with `>!` to hide it until you mouse over it.

Comment: @Douglas Zare I added the link to solutions at http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/

Comment: (1) If you want a formal answer you should formalize the success conditions. Is it this? "A deterministic communication protocol such that, for any singly-overlapping sets held by the sheriffs, the sheriffs always deduce the correct suspect, and the mob has no deterministic strategy to always guess the correct suspect." (2) This is very close to many types of problems in CS, such as zero-knowledge proofs and secure multiparty communication, but I don't know of this exact type of problem being studied (without complexity assumptions such as cryptography)....

Comment: @usul (1) Yes. (2) Me too. And this is my motivation.

Comment: Clearly the lynch mob can break public-key cryptography, so you can't use it.

Comment: Privacy-preserving joint computation is an important, and increasingly relevant problem in computer science. I don't know the state of knowledge about the set intersection problem, but you should check out the following papers: http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-24676-3_1 and http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-14577-3_13

Comment: @AlexeyUstinov The solution given by Addison (http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/11278) does not depend on the number of suspects and works whenever the suspect lists have a unique intersection and the total number of suspects is at least four.

Comment: @Yoav Kallus Addison gave wrong solution (look at the comments below his solution). In your refferences "datasets contain lists of elements taken from a LARGE domain" while our problem is about SMALL domain.

Comment: Do those who voted to close see a proof of this?

Comment: @AlexeyUstinov Also, why do you insist on the communication protocol being deterministic? There are arbitrary choices to be made, and if they are made in a deterministic way (say according to lexicographic order), they give more information than needed to the eavesdroppers. You should also specify that eavesdroppers have infinite computation power, to exclude cryptographic answers.

Comment: When I read the book years ago, I also thought about the puzzle for a different number of suspects and I think that I came to the conclusion that the puzzle is already solvable if the number of suspects is 6, but not solvable for 3. Unfortunately I don't remember much.

Comment: @YoavKallus, the reason I like determinism is that *every time* we run the protocol, it both (a) succeeds in identifying the suspect to the sheriffs and (b) succeeds in not identifying the suspect to the mob. I guess I was assuming that if the above can be done at all, then it can be done deterministically ... which I still think is true, but not sure of a proof....

Comment: I've asked this question (with 7 suspects) at Puzzling: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/12555/two-sheriffs-and-eavesdroppers-2

Comment: @domotorp: It would be interesting if you were able to reconstruct your solution for 6 suspects.

Comment: @Yoav: Sorry but I cannot, knowing myself, I would not take my claim at face value. I really think someone just ought to write a program to check the cases, it shouldn't be too complicated.

Comment: The probability that Alice named one of Bob's suspects is 1:5, so Eve is 80% sure of the culprit's identity. Wouldn't it be dreamy if there were a solution with a better probability? It's probably nothing but a fantasy...

Comment: Note also OP's follow-up question, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/203317/the-two-sheriffs-puzzle-2-threshold-for-security

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Here's a solution for the case of seven suspects that uses the Fano plane. Let the seven points of the Fano plane represent the seven suspects. Alice and Bob both reveal the name of the suspect completing a line with the two suspects on their list. There are now two cases to consider:

1. Alice and Bob did not name suspects on each other's lists. Then the suspicion (among the sheriffs) is reduced to the four suspects not named and not completing a line with the two suspects named. Alice knows that Bob is uncertain if Alice's list is the list which is correct or its complement. Same for Bob. Alice reveals her list. Bob reveals his. Both now know the culprit. Eve would also know, assuming she knew that we are in case 1, but she doesn't.
2. Alice named one of Bob's suspects, and since we are assuming their suspect lists have an intersection of size 1, Bob named one of Alice's suspects. Both sheriffs know this, but Eve doesn't. Also, both sheriffs now know who the culprit is. The rest of the conversation is only in order to not reveal to Eve that case 2 is occurring. Alice names two suspects that make a line with her first-announced suspect, but don't include Bob's first-announced suspect. Bob does the same.

The protocol is not deterministic when it falls into case 2, requiring arbitrary choice, but I fail to see why you want determinism.

Comment: Re your last sentence, but the protocol can be made deterministic by making one of the arbitrary choices.

Comment: Brilliant to use the Fano plane!

Comment: Note that Bob's last action in case 2 is a little more constrained, to avoid giving away that they're in case 2; the list Bob reveals has to overlap the one Alice reveals.  So he has to pick one of the two points Alice named, together with the remaining point on the line between it and the point he originally named.

Comment: @HarryAltman Bob does not need to be careful since there will always be exactly one point of intersection for all four possible choices of the last steps.

Comment: @usul, I don't think it can. Note that from Eve's point of view after Alice and Bob's first announcements, one instance of case 2 can match four different instances of case 1. If Alice and Bob have a deterministic choice in case 2, then they have to pick a single instance of case 1 to mimic, which means that the other three instances are never mimicked and always correspond to case 1.

Comment: @Yoav Kallus What it means "to name a suspect N"? Is it means to say "I suspect person N"?

Comment: @AlexeyUstinov, no, it just means to say their name. Here, if Alice or Bob say somebody's name at the beginning of the conversation, it actually means they don't suspect them.

Comment: @Yoav Kallus Do they choose names at random?

Comment: @AlexeyUstinov, did you read the answer? They choose the name that completes the line in the Fano plane determined by their list of suspects.

Comment: @Yoav Kallus Sorry, I didn't understand the beginning of your protocol correctly.

Comment: @Yoav Kallus Thank you for this amazing solution!

Comment: With probability 80% we are in case 1 --- so Eve knows the killer with probability 80% --- do you think this probability can be reduced?

Comment: @AntonPetrunin Good question (I see now it was also raise by disznoperzselo in the comments to the question). It would be nice to have a solution where Eve's best guess is correct with a lower probability, but I don't see how to adapt this solution in that direction. I don't see any reason that the probability couldn't be improved, but maybe the improved protocol will not be as nice and symmetric.